# ¿Como realizar esta estructura en Json desde SQL 2017?

Tags: sql

Deseo convertir esta estructura seleccionando dato desde tabla  al seleccioanrlo lo voy a convertir en JSON desde base de datos Sql 2017.
ADJUNTO MI QUERY

```
Select Medio_Pago AS [medio_pago] from Table_FacturacionElect 
where Comprobante = '22'  FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Deseo tener este resultado excato

```
 "medio_pago": [
        "sample string 1"
      ],
```

Comment: por favor revisa [ask] y de paso dale editar y mejora tu publicación, por ejemplo explicando como obtienes esa data y por que es que necesitas convertirla en JSON desde el gestor de bases de datos?

Comment: además aclara que gestor estas usando, es decir sql server o mysql? por que pusiste 2 etiquetas

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya actualice un poco mi formulacion de la preguntad